# Change ViewBag to Json array to plot barchart in .net MVC

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change ViewBag to Json array to plot a chart in  .net MVC framework. I try to parse Json based on solution I found previous questions but it displays nothing. My code is below.

**Controller**

```
public  ActionResult RimChart()
    {
        List<RimCalcs> listOfCategggories = null;

        Connectors aConn = Connectors.GetInstance();
        listOfCategggories = aConn.GetRimCalc();
        var dates = listOfCategggories.Select(x => x.Date);
        var profits = listOfCategggories.Select(y => y.Rprofit);

        ViewBag.Date = dates;
        ViewBag.profit = profits;

        return View();

    }
```

**Razor View**

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"
            },
            data: [
                {
                    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { label: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.profit)'), y: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Date)') },

                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    }
</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The content of your viewbag is not JSON. In order to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object, the thing you're parsing first needs to actually be JSON. On the server side you need to serialise your variable to a JSON string, and then store that string in the viewbag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**
You may want to serialize first and the do the parse

```
@{
        var profit = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.profit);
        var date = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Date);
}
```

```
 window.onload = function () {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"
            },
            data: [
                {
                    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { label: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(profit)'), y: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(date)') },

                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    }
```

Or you can Serialize directly on the controller

```
public  ActionResult RimChart()
    {
        List<RimCalcs> listOfCategggories = null;

        Connectors aConn = Connectors.GetInstance();
        listOfCategggories = aConn.GetRimCalc();
        var dates = listOfCategggories.Select(x => x.Date);
        var profits = listOfCategggories.Select(y => y.Rprofit);

        ViewBag.Date = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dates);
        ViewBag.profit = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(profits);

        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Agreed but I wouldn't use the obsolete JavaScriptSerializer. Even Microsoft stopped using it and started using Newtonsoft.JSON instead as the default serialiser

Comment: @ADyson yes you are right, I have edited the answer

Comment: It works perfectly (convert to array), but the chart is not showing up. Is there an error in my JavaScript code? Am using Canvas.js. I have also tried with Chart.js but the same. I notice that the "data" or y-axis is not populated. Thanks

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN my guess is that you are missing the `x` value on the `dataPoints` array, that's why isn't rendering.